# Cozero sets in C*-embedded

Tags: general-topology

Let $S$ be a $C^*$-embedded in a space $X$. Is it true that every cozero set of $S$ is in the form $U\cap S$ for a cozero set $U$ of $X$?

Comment: I think so. And the proof should be straightforward from the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Let $S$ be C<sup>*</sup>-embedded in $X$, and let $V \subseteq S$ be a co-zero set. Then there is a continuous $f : S \to [0,1]$ such that $V = f^{-1} ( (0,1] )$. But as $f$ is bounded and continuous, there is a continuous $g : X \to [0,1]$ such that $f = g \restriction S$. Then clearly $V = U \cap S$ where $U = g^{-1} ( (0,1] )$ is a co-zero subset of $X$.